# How to get a list of sql tables from Access VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba

I need to find a value on a sql database.
I connected all tables in access and wrote a simple code to get the value.
Now I would like to extend it to all possible sql databases working with a connection string but select FROM MSysObjects is not working on sql.
Any suggestion?

```
Azienda = SOC(Y)
sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID=sa;password=skipper;Initial
Catalog=" & Azienda & ";Data Source = server09;Use Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096"

conn.Open sConnString

Dim TN(1000) As String 'NOME TAB

strsql = "SELECT MSysObjects.Name AS table_name FROM MSysObjects"

filtro = " WHERE Left([Name],1)<>'~' AND Left([Name],4)<>'MSys' AND MSysObjects.Type In (1,4,6) order by MSysObjects.Name"

Dim CF As ADODB.Field

Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset

Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

With rst

.Open strsql & filtro, CONN, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly
```

Comment: Be more specific in regards to "is not working", are you getting an error, no results, results other than what you expected or your computer catches on fire?

Comment: Because MSysObjects is ONLY in Access. Other DBMS have their own convention. In sql server it is sys.objects, for just tables it would be sys.tables. And do yourself a huge favor and move your connection to a config somewhere and for heaven's stop using the sa account for applications.

Comment: Thanks Sean but sys.objects is giving me an error invalid object name on line .Open strsql & filtro, CONN, adOpenDynamic, adLockReadOnly it's the same error I get iwth my code.

Comment: sql application is not mine this is why I am using sa user